# At t == ..., step size is effectively zero; \ singularity or stiff system suspected

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I need to get a phase portrait for a non-linear oscillator, for this I wrote down the corresponding equations. 3 equations for different "a" which can take values from minus to plus infinity. In each equation, the last term is an expression for the nonlinearity of our oscillator. In general, the problem (error message `NDSolve::ndsz`) arises when I try to solve equations for "a" which value is more than zero. For example, if i change last term for another like that: (a*x)/(a+x), it works. Can't anderstand where is my mistake in the first case?
My code is:

```
δ = 0.1;
ω0 = 1;
α1 = 0.1;
α2 = 0;
α3 = -0.5;
Subscript[t, 0] = 0;
Subscript[t, 1] = 100;

x1 = DSolve[{x''[t] + 
  2δ*x'[t] + (ω0^2)*x[t] + α1/x[t]^2 == 0, 
x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, Subscript[t, 0], Subscript[t, 1]}];

x2 = DSolve[{x''[t] + 
  2δ*x'[t] + (ω0^2)*x[t] + α2/x[t]^2 == 0, 
x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, Subscript[t, 0], Subscript[t, 1]}];

x3 = DSolve[{x''[t] + 
  2δ*x'[t] + (ω0^2)*x[t] + α3/x[t]^2 == 0, 
x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, Subscript[t, 0], Subscript[t, 1]}];

Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. x1, {t, 0, 60}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
PlotLegends -> {"α = 0.1"}], 
ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. x2, {t, 0, 60}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
PlotLegends -> {"α = 0"}], 
ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. x3, {t, 0, 60}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotLegends -> {"α = -0.5"}]]
```

Comment: Only `NDSolve[]` and ilk can produce the `NDSolve::ndsz` error, yet you are using `DSolve[]` in your code. What am I missing?

Comment: You might try tracking down which command give the error and restrict your code to what is necessary.  If `DSolve` doesn't work, try `NDSolve`, if a numeric solution would be acceptable.  (It seems `x1` and `x3` fail.)

Comment: @J.M. I think inside `ParametricPlot`, `N[DSolve[..]]` is tried, which now calls `NDSolve`, when `DSolve` fails.

Comment: Yes, `DSolve` is unable to solve the `x1` and `x3` ODEs.  Incidentally, because the ODEs are autonomous, they can be reduced to first order, although it is unclear whether that would help.  Also, I would guess that, if `NDSolve` eventually is called, it would fail at the turning points of the nonlinear oscillators or when `x[t] == 0`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used NDsolve and it doesn't work too, than I tried to use Dsolve to see what changes and forgot to change it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ParametricNDSolveValue to solve your problem:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] +2 \[Delta]*x'[t] + \[Omega]0^2*x[t] +\[Alpha] x[t]^2 == 0,x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, t0, t1}, {\[Alpha]}]
(*ParametricFunction[ <> ] *)

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{sol[\[Alpha]][t], 
sol[\[Alpha]]'[t]}, {\[Alpha], {\[Alpha]1, \[Alpha]2, \[Alpha]3}}]], {t, t0,t1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Everything works, but you wrote last term as α*x[t]^2 but i need α/x[t]^2 and if change last it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be the singularity x==0.  If you set  `t1=1` everthing works!

Comment: Check the equilibrium of your ode `0 == \[Omega]0^2*x0  + \[Alpha] /x0^2`: Only for   `\[Alpha] <0` a real solution `x0>0`exists  .

Comment: Thank you for your answer!